# Pass form submission data to laravel from wordpress subfolder (or embed form)

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

I have a laravel project I inherited from another developer. It has a sub-folder with wordpress installed (for a separate CMS that is not integrated with the laravel project). What is needed is, on a wordpress page, there is a gravity form. On the form submission, I have to pass the form data over to the laravel (main public folder) project. Is there a way to pass over the data? I have tried to use the gravity form's redirect and just redirect the form submission to the main page. But, it doesn’t seem to collect the data. Anyone know how to do this?

The other option, would be to "embed" the laravel form. I know (or at least I think I know) the view/blade file that the form has. But, would need a way to embed it into a wordpress page. Didn’t know if that might be a possibility. Thanks!

Comment: The process for passing variables in the query string is pretty well [documented](https://docs.gravityforms.com/configuring-confirmations/#h-confirmation-type-redirect), and it is probably the easiest, so I'd continue down that path. If it doesn't work, post your setup more and we might be able to help more. Embedding the form should work, too, but that seems like a hassle. The third option is to create an API on the Laravel side that you populate in PHP, and the fourth option would be to talk directly to the Laravel database.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I have tried The parameters and redirection from gravity forms. But, on the laravel side, the previous developer seems to capture all requests and redirects them to home directory. How to I capture that from the routes in laravel and pass the Params to the correct controller?